# Searching only the first dimension of a 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, search, 2d

Let's say I have two arrays (one being one dimension and the next being 2d)

```
    int[] attack = {0,1};
    int[][] coords = {{0,1,2,3,4},{0,1,2,3,4}};
```

And I want to search for attack[0] in only the first dimension of coords?

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: You don't. The first dimension is an array of integers.

Comment: What do you mean my 'searching only the first dimension'? The first dimension of `coords` has the data type `int[]` and `attack[0]` is an `int`. You'll never find `attack[0]` in the first dimension of `coords` no matter what `attack[0]` is, in this case. Do you want to search the first 'element' of `coords`?

Comment: I see what you're saying, Matt Shank.  Maybe I could copy the first dimension of the 2d array to a standard one dimensional array and iterate through that new copied array to check for attack[0]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you mean?

```
for(int[] a : coords) {
    if(a[0] == attack[0]) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, thank you very much!!  So now what I need to do is check if the second row at that index equals attack[1]

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int element : coords[0]) {
    if(element == attack[0]) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```